# While loop, have two if i in statements

Tags: python, if-statement, time, while-loop

OK so two questions here.

First,I am trying to show start time. I am doing this with program_time. Second, I also want to show elapsed time. I would also like to show this in microseconds.

```
import time
a= time.time()
print a
while True:
    program_time= time.time()
    elapsed=program_time - a
    for i in [program_time]:
        print "%s\r" % i,
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is giving you problems?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Be aware that `time.time()` [may only return seconds](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time), not milliseconds, due to system limitations.

Comment: @acattle: Not really. As the documentation said, it depends on your system. Try running `time.time() - bool(time.sleep(0.1)) - time.time()` and see what that outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks almost correct. This should show the start time, and each subsequent program time as the while loop proceeds (albeit very quickly). Perhaps you need to perform some calculation in the loop?

```
import time
a = time.time()

print "Starting time is %s" % str(a)

while True:
    # Clear the screen each iteration to "recycle" the lines
    print chr(27) + "[2J"

    program_time = time.time();
    elapsed      = int(round((program_time - a) * 1000)) * 100

    print "Start time is %s" % a 
    print "Elapsed time is %s" % elapsed

    # Simulate some work
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I'd like it to recycle program time and elapsed time each loop on a single line instead of a new line... So I display program time on one line and elapsed time on another line. @louis

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just want to have the same two lines keep updating? See the edited code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is "why does my program output the current time instead of the elapsed time," the answer is "because `program_time` is being printed rather than `elapsed`."